# What are the ways in which access to a field by query can be changed?

Tags: apex, query, sosl, access

On a visualforce page with a controller, users could previously search on a custom contact field via SOSL.

A few weeks ago, something changed and users get no results back in the search as if they do not have access to the field/object. As an admin I still get results back on the search page, but these other users cannot.

They do not and have never had profile access to the field in question, but the Apex Class does not have sharing enforced.

In a non-updated sandbox org, users of the same profile and role can still search and get results.

In the production org, updating the profile to have access to the field allows users to query by this field, where previously, and proven in the non-updated sandbox, they did not need profile access to this field to get the results on the VFP with controller in question.

I have checked the following settings and am still unable to determine what has changed that is preventing users from getting results.

- Encryption Settings
- Sharing Settings
- Profile Object/Field Settings
- Permission Set Assignments
- Group Assignments (Related to Sharing)
- Apex Class Sharing
- Apex Class Access
- Audit Trail
- Field Level Security

Is there anything else I could be missing or am I overlooking one of the previous items?

Comment: You don't mention `Field Level Security`. Did you not check that?

Comment: I had not, but checked and they are not visible in both orgs (the org where this can be searched, and the org it cannot)

Comment: VFP the same in sandbox and prod?

Comment: Not the entire page, but this specific query. As an admin I see the results as I normally would and how the users used to, but the user can no longer in prod. Sharing on the apex class is not enforced on either.